# How to change time for waiting for next tap in gesture recogniser

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I need to implement two taps on view and three taps on the same view. How to check if should call handler for two or for three taps. 
According to some documentation I've add

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == doubleTapRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == tripleTapRecognizer {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

It seems to work fine, however I need to tap three times extremely fast, so sometimes it's not possible. 
How should I configure double or triple tap?

`tripleTapRecognizer` and `doubleTapRecognizer` are created with following configuration

```
private func setTripleTouchGestureRecognizer() -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tripleTapHandler(_:)))
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
    gesture.delegate = self
    return gesture
}

private func setDoubleTapGestureRecognizer() -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapHandler(_:)))
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    gesture.require(toFail: setTripleTouchGestureRecognizer())
    gesture.delegate = self
    return gesture
}
```

Comment: @matt what you mean is weird? 
Updated.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur He should be looking at the _actual_ gesture recognizers, not generating new ones.

Comment: @matt Okay, what if I don't know how many objects will be, which need to do something when tapped?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You seem to want to implement the delegate method `shouldBeRequiredToFailBy`. The way to do that is to examine the two gesture recognizers you are sent. You can easily see, for example, whether they are both tap gesture recognizers and how many taps each one requires — if that is what you want to do.

Comment: @matt Okay, so better will be if I prepare one doubleTapRecognizer and tripleTapRecognizer, and then always use only them, not creating new recognizer to each object which I am going to show?

Comment: You should not "prepare" anything. You should not compare with anything. Just look right at the two UIGestureRecognizers and decide whether the one should require the other to fail before recognizing.

Comment: @matt Well to be honest I'm not sure what you mean. I did some modifications to have the same as in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another) but still the same, sometimes it's identifying double tap, but should triple tap

Answer (score 0):

This is a system-level configuration:
The user need to go to `Settings->General->Accessibility->VoiceOver->Double-tap Timeout` to configure the timeout interval between taps. (Yes, this works for triple taps also, I guess since it's so rare, they just call it "Double-tap")

BTW, you should not create new TGRs in the delegate method. Instead, you can use the existing ones.

Comment: @Micgal AFAIK, no.